# How to add UTF-16 characters at the beginning of an existing file using sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a large script that generates many files and part of it doesn't work due to BOM missing. I have to work with the file named pagecounts-${_date} which is ultimately created like this:

```
cat $TMPDIR/*.filtered > $TMPDIR/pagecounts-${_date}
```

Then, I use sort and try to work with it in another script, but I get the BOM error. My guestion is, can I add BOM for utf-16 at the beginning of an already existing file? If yes, how can I achieve that?

I was thinking of using a temporary file like this:

```
cat $TMPDIR/*.filtered > $TMPDIR/tmp_pagecounts-${_date}
echo '\ufeff' > $TMPDIR/pagecounts-${_date}
cat $TMPDIR/tmp_pagecounts-${_date} | sort >> $TMPDIR/pagecounts-${_date}
```

But this way seems to chop off some of the UTF-16 characters.

Comment: You have *suddenly* introduced `sort` into the question that deals with adding a BOM (and won [the award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) in process). If `sort` chops off UTF-16 characters, that's a problem quite different from the missing BOM.

Comment: In addition UTF-16 is quite suspicious in and of itself. What kind of Unix program uses UTF-16 for writing files? Are you in a UTF-16 locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `echo -e` for printing the Unicode `utf-16` character sequence as is

```
sed "1s/^/$(echo -ne '\ufeff')/" "$TMPDIR"/pagecounts-${_date}
```

or use `printf` too

```
sed "1s/^/$(printf '\ufeff')/" "$TMPDIR"/pagecounts-${_date}
```

Confirm the same sequence to be accurate after doing a `hexdump -c` or `hexdump -C` on the same file

```
echo -ne '\ufeff' | hexdump -c
0000000 355 237 277 355 273 277
0000006
```

You can confirm these bytes to be consistent on applying to the file also.

The above `sed` commands just print the file contents to stdout, to modify the file in-place use the `-i` flag (`-i ''` is required for macOS's `sed`)

```
sed -i '' ...
```